# jet-image-loader is not working with aync methods

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I tried to use Jet-Image Loader on my windows 8 phone application and it works fine over forms but once i try to apply the Jet-Image caching technique over the aync methods which bind information on async mode it won't work, below is the code which i am using:

## XAML:

```
<ctl:LongListSelector x:Name="ListCards" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      LayoutMode="Grid"  ItemsSource="{Binding greetingsList}"
                      SelectionChanged="lstCards_SelectionChanged"
                      GridCellSize="210,170">enter code here
    <ctl:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="200" Height="170" VerticalAlignment="Center">                                  
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImgPath, Converter={StaticResource SampleJetImageLoaderConverter}}"
                           Width="180" Height="140"                                                
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Stretch="UniformToFill" />

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ctl:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</ctl:LongListSelector>
```

## Code:

```
public partial class card_List3 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public class GetGreetingSchema 
    {

    public Uri ImgPath
    {
        get { return _ImgPath; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _ImgPath, value);
        }
        }      
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GetGreetingSchema> greetingsList { get; private set; }
    public card_List3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        greetingsList = new ObservableCollection<GetGreetingSchema>();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);           
        try
        {
            await LoadDataAsync();             
        }
        catch (Exception listbindException)
        {
            ReusableMethods.LogStackTrace(listbindException);             
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        var dataSource = new Container().Resolve<IfellowsCollection>();           
        greetingsList = await dataSource.BindGreetingsList(CatId, Contenttype);
        ListCards.ItemsSource = greetingsList;
    }
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the JetImageLoader page is at https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader

Comment: Does greetingsList get populated when the await method returns?

Comment: I spoke to JetImageLoader team and as they have mentioned list item model has Uri typed property ImgPath with the image link, but BaseImageLoaderConverter can work only with string typed links, try to change type of ImgPath property to string from Uri.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question here :)

Issue is fixed, now `JetImageLoader` supports `Uri` as imageUrl param: https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader/issues/8